# Image of the upper half plane (or lower half plane) under the map $f(z)=z^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Prove that the image of the upper half plane under the map $f(z)=z^2$ is the $w$ plane with a cut along the positive real axis omitting the origin.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$ We define the upper half plane as $\mathbb{H}^+ =\{z\in \mathbb{C} : \ \text{Im}\ z >0\}$.

We want to find $f(\mathbb{H}^+)$.

Let $z \in \mathbb{H}^+$. Then $z$ can be written as $z=  re^{i\theta}$ where $r\in (0, +\infty)$ and $0<\theta <\pi$.

Therefore, $w= f(z) = f(re^{i\theta}) = r^2 e^{2i\theta}$. Take $w= \rho e^{i\alpha}$, where $\rho = r^2 \in (0, +\infty)$ and  $\alpha =2\theta \in (0, 2\pi)$.

Hence, $f(\mathbb{H}^+) = \mathbb{C}\setminus [0, +\infty)$. So, the image would be the $w$ plane with a cut along the positive real axis omitting the origin.

$\textbf{My Thought:}$ Similarly, the image under $f(z) =z^2$ would be the $w$ plane with a cut along the positive real axis omitting the origin.

Is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: Note that $r=0$ is false in the (open) upper half plane.

Comment: @coffeemath Should I change the range for $r$, i.e., $r\in (0, \infty)$?

Comment: Yes that's what I was hinting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the mapping w=$z^2$ is conformal on the upper plane. Consider the image of the line y=a (a>0)which lies in the upper plane. w= u+iv = $z^2$ = $(x+iy)^2$ =$ x^2 -y^2 +2xiy$=$x^2 -a^2 +2iax$. Equating real and imaginary parts we get
u=$x^2 -a^2$ and v=2ax. Eliminating x we get $v^2=4a^2(u+a^2)$ which is a parabola with vertex at ($-a^2$,0). As ‘a’ tends to zero, the parabolas move inside with vertex tending to the origin. So in the limiting case as ‘a’ positive tends to infinity the entire u-v plane is covered except [0 $\infty$). So the image of the upper plane is $\mathbb C$ -[0 $\infty$).